# Unity: After the game is reinstalled, the saved data in play game services is gone

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-unity-plugin

I creating a new game for android using unity engin and I face this probelm in Google Play Game Service.

I take all necessary steps to save data in play game services to save player progress in the cloud. After uninstalling the game from the device, I notice that the Play Game Service keeps the game in my list as played, and there is progress there, but after reinstalling it, the API returns empty data with a success status.

The code:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution("Data",
                DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, (status, metadata) =>
                {
                    switch (status)
                    {
                        case SavedGameRequestStatus.Success:
                            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(metadata, (requestStatus, bytes) =>
                            {
                                switch (requestStatus)
                                {
                                    case SavedGameRequestStatus.Success:
                                        callback(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)));
                                        Debug.Log("Data loaded");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        callback(null);
                                        Debug.Log("Data failed to Load: "+ status.ToString());
                                        break;
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                            callback(null);
                            Debug.Log("Data failed to Load: "+ status.ToString());
                            break;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what is its UID at the save end?

Comment: @BugFinder it player data object (serialized class)

Comment: ok so it makes sense then that if you remove it, and reinstall that it makes new token.

Comment: @BugFinder I did the same logic in my previous games and the date returned correctly after removing and reinstalling the game.